# HorizontalAnchor gives wrong value in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

The problem: Control.HorizontalAnchor or Control.VerticalAnchor gets a value out of the accepted range.

In the IDE window:
Debug.Print Btn.VerticalAnchor --> Result: 4864

In the Immediate window:
?Btn.VerticalAnchor --> 0

Same line. Same code.

I am stumped. Please help.

L.E.: apparently the value somehow gets distorted after
`If Btn.HorizontalAnchor = acHorizontalAnchorRight Then`

Comment: Edit question to show all relevant code. What event is this in? Exactly what are you trying to accomplish? I get 0 in both outputs.

Comment: From my testing, HorizontalAnchor (and VerticalAnchor) can have values of 0, 1, 2 only. No idea how you get 4864. I cannot replicate issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got nearly the same issue running **Microsoft Access 2013 x64 15.0.5349 (VBA 7.01)**.

For me the controls `HorizontalAnchor` property contains the value of the expected `AcHorizontalAnchor` enumeration plus `25344`.

So if the controls `HorizontalAnchor` is configured to `acHorizontalAnchorLeft` (0) it contains `25344`.
For `acHorizontalAnchorRight` (1) it contains `25345`.
And for `acHorizontalAnchorBoth` (2) it contains `25346`.

Comparing my value `25344` and your value `4864` I can see that their binary representation both contain additionally set bits in the higher byte:

| Decimal | Binary |
| --- | --- |
| 4864 | 1 0011 0000 0000 |
| 25344 | 110 0011 0000 0000 |

So the workaround I use is to ignore the high byte of HorizontalAnchor:

```vb
If (xControl.HorizontalAnchor And &HFF) = _
    AcHorizontalAnchor.acHorizontalAnchorLeft Then _
    Debug.Print "-> Left"

If (xControl.HorizontalAnchor And &HFF) = _
    AcHorizontalAnchor.acHorizontalAnchorRight Then _
    Debug.Print "-> Right"

If (xControl.HorizontalAnchor And &HFF) = _
    AcHorizontalAnchor.acHorizontalAnchorBoth Then _
    Debug.Print "-> Both"
```

It should be similar with `VerticalAnchor`.

Comment: good observation. thanks for the workaround. the way i did it myself was to store the value of anchoring property into a variable before whatever happens to mess it up. your solution is better since there is no additional variables. the thing is: why is it acting like this? could it have anything with the fact that i'm using some APIs in the form load event?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea (yet) why Access behaves like this.